# separate input group in python with a print

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in python I would like to create an interface which allows to enter text (number) and to cut the output with print to separate the different elements

for example

```
my texte = NNNNNNNNNKKVVVVVECPM
in output I would like = NNNNNNNNN KK VVVVV E C P M
```

thank you for your help good day

Comment: what is your approach so far and where do you have a problem? I'm sure you don't want us to solve it for you ;)  for generally working with strings and substrings in python have a look here: https://guide.freecodecamp.org/python/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to insert spaces between sequences, try this:

```
text = "NKNNPPOUSSEVNN"
l=[]
for i,char in enumerate(text):
    try:
        if text[i]==text[i+1]:
            l.append(char)
        else:
            if i==0: l.append(str(text[i])+" "+str(text[i+1]))
            else: l.append(" "+str(text[i+1]))
    except: pass
print("".join(l))
```

This gives:

```
N K NN PP O U SS E V NN
```

If you want to group the text on characters and then print out, use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools
text = "NKNNPPOUSSEVNN"
for i,grp in itertools.groupby(sorted(text)):
    print("".join(grp),end=" ")
```

This gives:

```
E K NNNNN O PP SS U V
```

Answer (score 0):

hello thank you for the answer my main problem is that my numbers are separated by check I can display my text but I want separation

voici mon programe

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *


class MyWindow(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.__code = StringVar()

        label = Label( self, text="Scanner le code barre:")
        label.pack()

        code = Entry(self, textvariable=self.__code )
        code.focus_set()
        code.pack()

        button = Button( self, text="Vérifier!", command=self.doSomething)
        button.pack()

        self.geometry( "400x300" )
        self.title( "Entry widget usage" )

    def doSomething(self):
        print( "ticket restaurant " + self.__code.get() )


window = MyWindow()
window.mainloop()
```